# SQLite multiple where in the same column

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
Char1       Char2       Difficulty
--------------------------------------------------
jon          sara          1
pablo        victor        2
laura        patricia      1
marta        juanjo        3
marina       goku          4
```

I want to select all the rows where difficulty = 1 and difficulty = 2. I have tried to do:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + DatabaseOpenHelper.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + " LIKE '1%'" + " AND " + DatabaseOpenHelper.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + " LIKE '2%'"
```

But it's not working, I am new to SQLite so I will appreciate any explanation with the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Since the Difficulty column is INT-type, why are you using LIKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

1. You did not actually describe your problem beyond "it's not working".
2. You'd need whitespace between column names and the `LIKE` keyword.
3. You don't need `LIKE` at all. Use `=1` in place of `LIKE '1%'` etc.
4. To combine multiple conditionals, you probably want `OR` in place of `AND`. A single row column cannot be `1` and `2` at the same time.

Comment: They did explain the problem. i.e. What I tried isn't working, why not.

Comment: @mascoj - Almost, except "It's not working" in this case can be interpreted as a SQL syntax error or no results returned.

Comment: I forgot the whitespace between column names when I wrote the post, but thanks anyway. I will follow your advices, In this case I should have used OR as you mentioned, I didn't think about that.